# Definition of determinantal variety.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry

I'm completely new to Algebraic Geometry and am reading the definition of determinantal variety and this might seem to be a silly question. The definition of Determinantal variety (from Wikipedia) is that:

> Given $m$ and $n$ and $r < \min(m, n)$, the determinantal variety $Y_r$ is the set of all $m \times n$ matrices (over a field $k$) with rank $\le r$. This is naturally an algebraic variety as the condition that a matrix have rank $\le r$ is given by the vanishing of all of its $(r + 1) \times (r + 1)$ minors.

I don't understand why a matrix $A$ with rank $r$ will have $(r + 1) \times (r + 1)$ minors? Looking through the ways to calculate minors I still don't get...Thanks for helping!

Comment: That is not the *number* of minors but the *dimension* of a submatrix. A minor is the determinant of that matrix. All those minors must be equal to zero.

Comment: @WimC Why would those minors have dimensions $(r+1) \times (r+1)$? I thought if $A$ has dimension $n$ and a minor has dimension $n - 1$? So if $A$ has rank of $r$ then a minor has rank $r - 1$?

Comment: A minor just means the determinant of a square submatrix, so it can be the determinant of a $a \times a$-matrix for any $a \in \{0,\ldots,\min(m,n)\}$. The phrase *all of its $(r+1)\times(r+1)$ minors* means that you only look at the minors that have size $(r+1)\times(r+1)$. Thus, $(r+1)\times(r+1)$ should be viewed as an adjective, rather than a count.

Comment: @Remy Thanks! But I'm still a little confused. Why are we looking at minors with rank $r+1$ instead of $r-1$ (if the original matrix has rank only $r$)?

Comment: Because if one of the $(r+1)\times(r+1)$ minors is nonzero, then the rank is at least $r + 1$, which is what you want to exclude.